# Sampling random sets of integers with bounded range

Tags: probability, random, sampling

How can we randomly sample a set $S$ of $k$ integers from the range $[1, n]$ such that:

1. The set satisfies $\max(S) - \min(S) \leq w$.
2. Each integer in $[1, n]$ has an equal chance of being in the set. If this is not possible, it should be as close as possible (minimizing the variance of probability).
3. 1 and 2 permitting, the method is as uniformly random as possible. That is, the maximum entropy distribution under constraints 1 and 2.

We have $k < w$.

Are there any efficient methods? Methods that have some bias but get close?

Comment: Your desiderata/constraints may be inconsistent.  Suppose $k=100$ and $w=2$.  How will you *ever* select integers with equal probabilities holding to the range constraint?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork We have $k < w$, I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork And I also made #2 a soft constraint so a solution always exists. I am also interested in approximations that get close in case an exact solution is difficult.

Comment: I have no idea how to approach this in general, but you should be able to get (numerically if not in closed form) the answer for, say, $w=1, k=2,n=5$. (Guessing the appropriate relative probabilities of the four valid sets $S$ is itself interesting.) Maybe attacking the cases where $k=w+1$ would be a good place to start. (Note there may be no exact solution. There is definitely not if $k=3,w=2,n=5$ as 3 must be in $S$)

Comment: Sorry, I misread the condition. However the max and min of 3 consecutive integers differ by only 2, so (unless I’m really misunderstanding), you only need to require $k\le w+1$ for there to be a valid $S$.

Comment: @SteveKass Sorry, you are right about that. I do have $k < w$ in my original problem though.

Comment: Got it. Still, the case when $k+1=w$, even though it’s not part of your question, might be tractable and a reasonable starting point for how to attack the general question.

Comment: @SteveKass I would actually consider starting at $k = 2$, which I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Does $S$ consist of $k$ distinct integers?

Comment: If $k=2$ and $w=n-1$, the uniform distribution over all $2$-subsets works, and $k=2,n=4$ has a solution (not necessarily unique) choosing equiprobable $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$, so maybe try numerically working on a small nontrivial case like $k=2, w=3, n=5$?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes. So you could say we're taking from $[1, n]$ without replacement when constructing a set $S$.